# Modifying apacite reference style: Comma after booktitle

Tags: bibliographies, apa-style

I am using a customized [apacite](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apacite) style for my bibliography. The reference guide of a journal demands a comma instead of a period after the book title.  Any idea how to define the comma in the .bst file? I think it must be somewhere in the `FUNCTION {book}` section. I have already managed to delete the period by deleting `add.period$` here:

```
 { format.authors                          start.new.block
  format.year.check                       output.dot.new.block
  format.btitle.vol.edition.editor.trans
  format.type.number                      connect.with.space.check
  add.period$
}
```

A sample reference should look like this:

Coleman, J.S. (1990). *Power and the Structure of Society*, New York: W.W. Norton & Company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `add.period$` with `"," *`. `*` is an internal function for use in `.bst` files. It takes two arguments, `x` and `y`, and concatenates them. The syntax is `xy*`.<sup>1</sup> So if you change the part of the `.bst` file that you identified to be:

```
{ format.authors                          start.new.block
  format.year.check                       output.dot.new.block
  format.btitle.vol.edition.editor.trans
  format.type.number                      connect.with.space.check
  "," *
}
```

Then this will concatenate `,` with the string that is being created by the previous functions.

If you save this new version as `myapacite.bst` and place it in your `TEXMFHOME` folder, then you can use the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{coleman1990,
author = {Coleman, J. S.},
title = {Power and the Structure of Society},
publisher = {W. W. Norton \& Company},
address = {New York},
year = {1990}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{apacite}
\usepackage{natbib}

\begin{document}

\citet{coleman1990}

\bibliographystyle{myapacite}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

---

1. This—and more information about functions for editing `.bst` files—can be found in [Tame the BeaST](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf). In particular, information about `*` is on p. 33.